# Как перевести дату в формат dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Как перевести дату 2018-05-27T16:45:00+03:00
в формат '27-05-2018 00:17:14', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

Comment: ты всё ещё не хочешь в moment.js?

Comment: в библиотеке, которую ты используешь, [всё есть для решения вопроса](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/format).

Comment: как через момент сделать

чтобы время из ИСО переводилось в мск время

Comment: "исо" - формат, "мск" - таймзона. наверное, у тебя есть время в таймзоне z1, а показать ты хочешь в z2. так вот, moment при манипуляциях приведёт дату к таймзоне указанной у пользователя дефолтной

Comment: мне нужно еще в мск формат перевести как-то
чтобы время в мск счиалось

Comment: да. я это делаю на сервере
мне приходит дата с tz1, а мне надо на сервере привести ее к tz2 (мск)

Comment: как это сделать

Comment: werty, я помню, что у тебя кейс: пользователь оставляет заявку об обратном звонке. пользователь в любой тайм-зоне, оператор в любой другой тайм-зоне. я бы решал проблему так: с клиента приходит дата с его тайм-зоной, на беке перевожу в utc и в базу (в заявку) кладу датувремя и, отдельно, клиенсткую таймзону. при показе в админке автоматом считаю в таймзону оператора и показываю из какой тайм-зону пользователь. js-объект Date, кажется, сам умеет переводить в нужную для показа тайм-зону. а форматировать для показа можно вообще чем угодно, хоть template string, хоть твоей либой

Comment: посмотри что в консоли тебе выведет `(new Date('2018-05-27T16:45:00+00:00')).toString()`

Comment: Мне теперь нужно так
на фронте юзер выбирает дату, я все равно епревожу ее в ИСО (нужно для других целей), на бэк приходит она в виде

 2018-05-27T16:45:00+03:00 и я ее записываю в первую бд в таком виде

и теперь мне надо записывать ее в другую базу данных в таком формате чтобы она хранилась

'27-05-2018 00:17:14', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

Comment: Sun May 27 2018 19:45:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)

в консоли